# Columns Order Changed at Runtime in DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

**DataGridView** has 7 columns with headers (**ID, TITLE, AUTHOR, GENRE, PRICE, PUBLISH, DESCRIPTION**). On data in datagridview from xml file, two columns order is changed and new order is (**ID, AUTHOR,TITLE, GENRE, PRICE, PUBLISH, DESCRIPTION**).
What is reason behind this ?

Reading from the xml file

```
Application.DataSet dsFileData = new DataSet("Books"); 
dsFileData.ReadXml(lSoruceFile); 
dgvBooksDetails.DataSource = dsFileData; 
dgvBooksDetails.DataMember = "book";
```

Comment: Are you generating the xml ? How is the xml data related to the grid, please shed some light on the same

Comment: Well,I'm not generating xml but reteriveing data from xml and providing it to DataGridView control on WinForm Application.                                                 DataSet dsFileData = new DataSet("Books");         dsFileData.ReadXml(lSoruceFile);                       dgvBooksDetails.DataSource = dsFileData;     dgvBooksDetails.DataMember = "book";                               By using this code you can read xml file data and populate it in the grid. I hop you got your point.

Comment: Well you don't need to specify the `DataMember` for `Dataset` with only one table (should be `Books`), so have defined the Columns and assigned their `DataMember` property ?

Comment: This is for to selecting data from sub elements in xml. This can vary by xml file strcture.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` property to false.

Comment: No idea what Auto generate has to do with this ?

Comment: When AutoGenerateColumns is set to true it will create columns automaticaly based on data source and keep the same order. When you set it to false it will take your columns instead.

Comment: I suspect in that case it would create additional columns in addition to what you already have

Comment: I can confirm this was my problem and @Vale you are also correct. If you're missing columns and have AutoGenerateColumns set to true this will indeed create those missing columns but as we're seeing it also like to prioritize the order of columns based on the record set and not how the columns are setup via the designer.